# Make a PHP upload form: "move_uploaded_file" work with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a picture upload form powered with dropzone.js (http://www.dropzonejs.com/):

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/frameworks/dropzone/upload.php" class="dropzone" style="margin: 100px; border:solid; "></form>
```

This works fine!
But the upload.php file won't properly upload my images...

```
$ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1

$storeFolder = "uploads";   //2

echo "√ Launched upload.php";

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3             

    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4
    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  //5

    echo "<br>Target Path: ".$targetPath;
    echo "<br>Target File: ".$targetFile;

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6
    echo "<br>√ move_uploaded_file";
 }
```

The move_upload_file doesn't seem to work properly......
Any hints?

Errors:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/var/www/vhosts/jtc.ae/httpdocs/pre/wp/wp-content/themes/Amazing_japan_HP/frameworks/dropzone/uploads/kimono's at JTC.jpeg):
**failed to open stream: Permission denied in** 
/var/www/vhosts/jtc.ae/httpdocs/pre/wp/wp-content/themes/Amazing_japan_HP/frameworks/dropzone/upload.php on line 25 
**Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move** '/tmp/phpDXnFKq' **to** '/var/www/vhosts/jtc.ae/httpdocs/pre/wp/wp-content/themes/Amazing_japan_HP/frameworks/dropzone/uploads/kimono's at JTC.jpeg' **in** /var/www/vhosts/jtc.ae/httpdocs/pre/wp/wp-content/themes/Amazing_japan_HP/frameworks/dropzone/upload.php on line 25
```

Comment: seeing `$post_id = $_GET['post_id'];` suggests that your form is using a GET method. Uploading requires a POST method with a valid enctype. Forms with no method defaults to GET. We also don't know where your file input is.

Comment: Can you share example output of `$tempFile` and `$targetFile`?

Comment: ok, I'm out of this loop. Another runaway.

Comment: rnevius: How do I share an example output of $tempFile and $targetFile?
Fred, what do you mean with a runaway?

Comment: I removed the $post_id  as I don't need it yet, and the php file echos all the way to the: √ move_uploaded_file
However, the files just don't get saved.

Comment: I mean the results of the `echo` statements.

Comment: Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1');` to the beginning of the file and see if any errors are displayed with the upload.  File permissions on the target path may not be correct.

Comment: It simply looks like you don't have write access in your target directory: `/var/www/vhosts/jtc.ae/httpdocs/pre/wp/wp-content/themes/Amazing_japan_HP/frameworks/dropzone/uploads`. I assume this is the target directory, because it is a subdirectory of the directory `upload.php` is in, and that's how you built that string too. The parth of the scripts and the path of the file stream PHP failed to open are both in the error message.

Comment: Is it dangerous if I have write access there?